# How to print changed lines in git commit?

Tags: git

I need to know in sequence of commits how many line was changed. I know I can use this command to fetch changed lines in one commit. but I need a command for many commit.

```
git diff --stat c269d50 152bf18
```

Comment: You could make something like this ```git diff @~3..@``` to see the changes in the 3 latest commits.

Comment: I need aggregated values of changes per commit

Answer (score 2):

```
git log --stat
```

See the docs for [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) and [`--stat`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---statltwidthgtltname-widthgtltcountgt)